# How to make a textview scrollable in BottomSheetDialogFragment while keeping the sliding actions of BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android

```
TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

I have tried this but I can not scroll down, BottomSheet closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BottomSheetDialogFragment get an instance of the BottomSheetDialog

```
    private lateinit var bottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialog

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)
        dialog.setOnShowListener { it ->

            bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
    }
  }
```

and use it for changing the behavior. as scrolling textview closes BottomSheet we need to set a ScrollChangeListener to disable the scrolling of BottomSheet for that moment

```
textview.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
                // Do something when the scroll positions change
                bottomSheetDialog.behavior.isDraggable = false
            }
```

Now re-enable the touch behavior of BottomSheet using

```
textview.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
                when (motionEvent.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN-> {
                        bottomSheetDialog.behavior.isDraggable = false
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP-> {
                        bottomSheetDialog.behavior.isDraggable = true
                    }
                }
                false
            }
```

For extensive control of BottomSheetDialogFragment you can use this listener for particular work

```
            try {
    // Use reflection to get the behavior field
    val behaviorField: Field = bottomSheetDialog.javaClass.getDeclaredField("behavior")
    behaviorField.isAccessible = true
    val behavior = behaviorField.get(bottomSheetDialog) as BottomSheetBehavior<*>
    // Set the callback to prevent sliding down
    behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {

        }

    })
} catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
} catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```